# How to create an anonymous class of a protocol in Objective-C

Tags: ios, objective-c, anonymous-class

The following code snippet is in Java. How can we get anonymous class implementations in Objective C?

```
//MyDelegate is an interface

MyDelegate delegate=new MyDelegate() {
@Override
public void onDelegateResponse(int responseType,NSString data)
  {


  }
};

//DFNodesControl is a normal java class
DFNodesControl obj=new DFNodesControl();
obj.makeRequest(delegate,currentNode);
```

Comment: In obj-C you never override a method of protocol, since in protocol the method is not at all defined. It is only declared.

Comment: In other words (re: @AnoopVaidya's comment) an ObjC protocol is like a Java Interface. If you define your class to implement the protocol, you're required to provide the methods for all required protocol methods, and you have the option to provide those the protocol declares as optional.

Comment: If you understand both Java and Objective C please try to understand the question and provide a solution. If my question title was wrong suggest an edit. Downgrading is just not the solution.

Comment: Have you got your `@protocol` defined already? What Obj-C code do you have? (show it)

Comment: @Wain Yes I have my protocol class created and I've also implemented it for few of my classes. But now I need to do this inside a method.Please help!!

Comment: Show the code you have. Either instantiate a class to pass as a parameter or describe your interface in detail so alternate approaches can be offered...

Comment: Yep, you can do it with 3rd-party libraries, read my full answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/33096839/440168

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you want to use [anonymous classes](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/anonymousclasses.html).

Objective-C doesn't have this exact feature as of now.  See the question ["Objective-C equivalent to Java's anonymous classes in class methods"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3770359/objective-c-equivalent-to-javas-anonymous-classes-in-class-methods).

You can create blocks in Objective-C, though.  They work like regular functions and can be passed around and reused.  You'd have to change your interface to take a block as a delegate instead of an object in this case.  Or you use a simple wrapper class;  Among provides an [example for this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17675006/1460929) in the aforementioned SO question.

See [Apple's block programming docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/cocoa/Conceptual/Blocks/Articles/00_Introduction.html) for details.

Comment: Well that answers my question. Thanks alot ctietze.

Comment: You're welcome. To prevent further downvoting, you should probably add "anonymous class" to the question.  As you state the question at the moment, it seems as if you want to know something about `@protocol`, which isn't quite true.

Answer (score 0):

In Objective-C you create a class which implements the protocol and then you implement each of the required methods specified in the `@protocol`.

There is no 'default' implementation for an `@protocol` that you can use (and thus override the default implementations).

Comment: Thanks for the response. But what if I don't want my class to implement the protocol  but just create an object like my Java code snippet is doing

Comment: Then you need to create another class which implements the protocols. Java is big on anonymous classes, Obj-C isn't...

Comment: Yeah got that Wain . Thanks for your time. The following comment helped me .[http://stackoverflow.com/a/17675006/1258606]